# JUnit+maven. Как сделать что-то до всех тестов и после них?

Tags: maven, тестирование, junit

Мне кажется, что я выучил **JUnit** вдоль и поперёк. Но попалась такая задачка, когда коннект нужно получать долго, максимум один, а конце нужно закрывать, и посередине тесты.
При этом интерфейс последовательный. Это я решил синхронизацией операций `read/write`, теперь все потоки ждут своей очереди на общение с устройством.
С одной стороны, можно прописать открытие и закрытие в блоках `@BeforeClas/AfterClass` + добавить к операции открытие ожидание освобождения порта, но это криво и тесты будут долгие, открытие дорогая операция.

Как бы так сделать?
 Если создать свой **TestRunner** или **Suite**, то **idea** и **maven** запустят и то, и другое, чем поломают всё.

Comment: [failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/single-test.html) не рассматривали? [Применительно к suite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792886/running-a-junit4-test-suite-in-maven-using-maven-failsafe-plugin)

Comment: @enzo, спасибо. Это интересный вариант. такое ещё не попадалось. Везде на форумах твердят только одно, что тесты должны быть независимыми. Они вроде как и независимы, но им нужна подготовленная среда. А чтобы было совсем правильно, наверное, нужно было бы использовать Mockito и имитировать устройство.

Comment: @enzo - это решение! Я уже проверил. Сделайте нормальный ответ, и я его подтвержу. Ещё раз убеждаюсь, что со stackoverflow безвыходных ситуаций не бывает.

Answer (score 2):

В общем, это решение будет полезно всем, кто хочет тестировать последовательно и в заданном порядке.

1. Создаёт свиту, где в аннотации перечисляем классы в порядке исполнения:

   ```
   @RunWith(Suite.class)
   @Suite.SuiteClasses({OpenConnection.class,
                   GetServerIdTest.class,
                   ModbusStatusCodesTest.class,
                   ModbusSerialTransactionTest.class,
                   CloseConnection.class})
   public class OrderedTestSuite {}
   ```
2. В pom.xml добавляем плагин:

   ```
   <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <includes>
                   <include>**/OrderedTestSuite.class</include>
               </includes>
           </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. Profit!